# Python, Pymysql, Inserted rows do not apper in the database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have this program in Python:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(<stuff here>)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
    INSERT INTO aderenti (nome, comune, provincia)
    VALUES ('Mario', 'Spinea', 'VE');
    ''')
```

the code runs fine, and if I run the SQL command in MySQL workbench a new row appears with the selected values. But if I run this code in Python, no new row appears. How is this possible?

Comment: You need to call `conn.commit()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it right now. Thogh I have previously added rows with Python without using conn.commit(), and it worked. So when do I have to use it and when I don't?

Comment: Use it to commit the transaction

Answer (score 2):

You already got the answer. as a side note include

```
autocommit=True
```

in your connection. It's just easy to have in connection.